# Dictionary implementation over BST

Tags: java, dictionary, implementation, binary-search-tree

Hy there, i'm new in java and I need to implement a dictionary over a Binary Search Tree but I really have no idea where to start from.
I have to store in this dictionary some Students having a name and age. 
So in the BST i will store the ages but where do I store the name of the student and how do I connect a name with a age field.

I would appreciate if you have an exemple of implementation for something like this, not necessairly all the code, but just the begining, so I cand start. If you don't have it in java, a c++ code is also good.

Comment: Do you know (1) what BST means; (2) how to build a BST with any payload (contents); (3) what kind of payload might be appropriate for a "dictionary"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary is a datastructure that maps keys to values and allows querying the value for a given key. A binary search tree also has keys (which are used for the search) and can also have further payload data (the values). So a BST with payload data is actually already a dictionary.

So, start by writing a usual BST implementation (cf. Wikipedia for simple implementations, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). Add a payload attribute to the nodes. Add a function `lookup(key)` that will first search the node with key `key` (using usual BST lookup) and return the payload attribute of that node. Et voila, there you have your dictionary.

Comment: So having this representation of a BST: http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Internal_repr i just add private string name in the node and that's all? But what if I have to store more things in the dictionary, not just the name, can I make some kind of typedef so I can store an object in the node?

Comment: of course, simply store an object containing all data you need instead of only a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources for creating a simple binary search tree on the Internet. A dictionary is simply defined as a datastructure that allows you to retrieve a value given a key. A binary search tree already does this. What you really need to do is create a `Student` class and then implement the `Comparable` interface in the `Student` class. This `compareTo` method would then sort the students by age (assuming age is a field on the `Student` class).

Something akin to:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    public Integer age;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return this.getAge().compareTo(o.getAge);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Thanks.